# sql + php show categories with infinit sub-categories

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
    category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    parent INT DEFAULT NULL
);
```

How can build the select SQL from the table so in php I can obtain a full tree of categories and sub-categories? I also want to check if a item has or not children because I want to add a class attribute.

Example:

- Electronics

  - Smarthphones

    - iPhone

      - iPhone 5s
      - iPhone 6
      - iPhone 6s
    - Samsung
  - TV
- Food

And the subcategories can be more than this example.

I could use this function in php to display the menu:

```
function treeview($array, $id = 0)
{

  foreach ($array as $arr)
  {

     if($arr[parent]==$id) {

     echo $arr[category_id].' '.$arr[parent].' '.$arr[name].'<br />';
     treeview($array, $arr['category_id']);

     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the commonly used structure which Andrey Telesh demonstrated, you could do the following:

```
<?php
function executeSQLThenFetchAllRowsAsAssoc($sql)
{
    global $pdo;
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
function buildTree($parent = null)
{
    if(empty($parent)){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent` is null";
    }else{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent`=$parent";
    }
    $rows=executeSQLThenFetchAllRowsAsAssoc($sql);
    $data = array();
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $cat=buildTree($row['category_id']);
        $data[] = array('children'=>$cat,'id'=>$row['category_id'],'parent'=>$row['parent'],'name'=>$row['name']);
    }
    return $data;
}

function displayIt($cats,$depth=0)
{
    if($depth==0){echo '<ul>';}
    foreach($cats as $cat)
    {
    $hasChildren=count($cat['children'])>0;
    $class=$hasChildren?' class="menu-item-has-children"':'';
    echo '<li'.$class.' data-children="'.count($cat['children']).'">'.$cat['name'];
    if($hasChildren){echo '<ul>';displayIt($cat['children'],$depth+1);echo '</ul>';}
    echo '</li>';
    }
    if($depth==0){echo '</ul>';}
}


$pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=my_database_name;', 'my_username', 'my_password');
$tree=buildTree();
displayIt($tree);
```

No closing `?>` is required. Just make sure to substitute `my_database_name`, `my_username`, and `my_password` at the end with your own settings.
Yes, this code will run by itself.
The output will is:

```
<ul><li class="menu-item-has-children" data-children="2">Electronics<ul><li class="menu-item-has-children" data-children="2">Smarthphones<ul><li class="menu-item-has-children" data-children="3">iPhone<ul><li data-children="0">iPhone 5s</li><li data-children="0">iPhone 6</li><li data-children="0">iPhone 6s</li></ul></li><li data-children="0">Samsung</li></ul></li><li data-children="0">TV</li></ul></li><li data-children="0">Food</li></ul>
```

The data I tested it on was:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;


INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `name`, `parent`) VALUES
(1, 'Electronics', NULL),
(2, 'Smarthphones', 1),
(3, 'iPhone', 2),
(4, 'Food', NULL),
(5, 'Samsung', 2),
(6, 'iPhone 5s', 3),
(7, 'iPhone 6', 3),
(8, 'iPhone 6s', 3),
(9, 'TV', 1);
```

For speed concerns, I'd recommend caching the categories as a serialized php object after you've determined the tree hierarchy with `buildTree()`. You might also be interested in just caching the HTML output you want directly, or do both. Whenever the categories table is updated, just update the cache. And by cache, I mean have a separate PHP file which you include into your project so you have the data available without bothering the database.

Comment: Your answer is great but, using my updated code from question how can I determine if current item has a child? You would say to make a select but I want this function to be like a helper to use it in multiple places. I am implementing in codeigniter. This sould be my full code: http://pastebin.com/r2y6t6vt and as you see there I need current_item_have_child .

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the class if an element has children. Also note I only had to edit `displayIt()` to achieve the result. The structure being returned from `buildTree()` still remains unchanged and could have been cached when you made such a change on the view.

Comment: Thank you, works great. I accepted as answer. Could you also provide me the version without echo and return $html; ? I am trying to do this with $html .= but no success.

Comment: Just use output buffering: `ob_start();` and `ob_get_clean()`, or define a public string variable, and with each recursion append the output to the public string variable. Then when the loop finishes reference the public variable.

Comment: I used a third param to displayIt, $html and replaced echo with $html .= to avoid defining other variables outside function. But no success.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use recursive methodologic:

```
function buildTree($parent = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `parent` " . (is_null($parent) ? 'IS NULL' : "= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($parent) . "'");
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row['children'] = buildTree($row['category_id']);
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data
}
$categories = buildTree();
```

Comment: Using my code I would like to know how to check if current item have children. Please read question.

Answer (score 1):

I use reference ( "&" ) in this method:

```
function _getTree($tree_details){

 $refs = array();
   $list = array();

  foreach ($tree_details as $data) {
     $thisref = &$refs[ $data['branch_id'] ];

      $thisref['branch_name']         = $data['branch_name'];
        $thisref['parent_id']           = $data['parent_id'];
        $thisref['branch_id']         = $data['branch_id'];

       if ( empty($data['parent_id']) ){ 
           $list[ $data['branch_id'] ]     = &$thisref;
        } else {
         $refs[ $data['parent_id'] ]['children'][ $data['branch_id'] ] = &$thisref;
      }

 }

 //check reviews tree 
  if( !empty($list) && count($list) ){
       return $list;
  }
  return false;

} // getTree
```

**This method will return associative array of all categories, and then you must use another method which will drawing html with using recursive function:**

```
function drawBranchesSelectBox($branches_tree=NULL, $branch_id = 0, $options_string = '', $separator = '') {

if(empty($branches_tree)){
   return false;
}

//loop through children
foreach ($branches_tree as $branches) {

  $is_selected = ( $branch_id == $branches["branch_id"] ? ' selected="selected" ' : '' );
    $options_string .= '' . $separator . $branches["branch_name"] . '' . "\n";

    //check for subbranches
    if (@is_array($branches['children']) && @count($branches['children'])) {
       //call same method to get children
     $options_string = drawBranchesSelectBox($branches['children'], $branch_id, $options_string, $separator . '    ');
  }


} //foreach

return $options_string;

} //drawBranchesSelectBox
```

Comment: Using my code I would like to know how to check if current item have children. Please read question.